# How to set default value for mat-select?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-material

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]='selected' >
   <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language" >
      {{language}}
   </mat-option >
</mat-select>
```

this is my html

```
selected:string
constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore,private globals:GlobalsService) { 
  console.log(this.globals.userUid);
  this.firestore.collection('customers').doc(this.globals.userUid).get().subscribe(function(doc){
    if(doc.exists){
      console.log(doc.data()["language"]);
      this.selected  = doc.data()["language"]
    }
  })
  for (let index = 0; index < avaibleLanguages.length; index++) {
    const language:string = avaibleLanguages[index]
    this.languages.push(language)
  }}
```

in the console.log I see that I received the right language from firebase but it didn't set it as default select. all the other things here work

Comment: If you change the callback function of subscribe to the inline function, you don't loose `this` instance. You need to change it like `.subscribe(doc => {...}) `

Answer (score 0):

just need to put the value in local variable.

```
var local
    this.firestore.collection('customers').doc(this.globals.userUid).get()
    .subscribe(doc =>{
      if(doc.exists){
        local = doc.data()["language"]
      }
    },err => console.log(err),()=>{this.selected = local }
    )
    for (let index = 0; index < avaibleLanguages.length; index++) {
      const language:string = avaibleLanguages[index]
      this.languages.push(language)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If symptoms persist, use ChangrDetectorRef: find out here https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

```
...
constructor (private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

private someFn(): void {
    this.changeDetector.detach();
    this.changeDetector.reattach();
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}
...
```